# GetWindowRect in UWP

Tags: uwp, dllimport

Since AppDiagnostics permissions have been added, I think it should be possible to get the size of the window currently in the foreground. Here is what I have already tried:

```
    async private void DoThing()
    {
        Rect angle = GetRectValues();

        reportString += angle.Y + " ";
        reportString += angle.X + " ";
        reportString += angle.Height + " ";
        reportString += angle.Width;
    }

    private unsafe Rect GetRectValues()
    {

        IntPtr hWID = GetForegroundWindow();

        Rect angle;

        Rect* pAngle = &angle;

        GetWindowRect(GetForegroundWindow(), pAngle);

        return angle;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    private unsafe static extern Boolean GetWindowRect(IntPtr intPtr, Rect* lpRect);
```

It runs, and also returns values. The problem is, these values are pretty weird.

```
3.47522019152555E-43 1.50919844607783E-42 1.60448674165192E-42 3.50885135466934E-42
```

These are the values for an explorer window running in the middle of my screen. They change when I move the window, but I don't know how to interprete them. Also, they change to NaN if the window is fullscreen. Unless I cast them to integers, in which case the values turn into `-2147483648 -2147483648 0 0` 
 for whatever reason.

How do I use this method correctly, and how do I interprete these values?

Comment: Just FYI, the Windows Store doesn't currently allow this API so even if you get if go to work, you will be limited to side loading or enterprise installs. Also note that most of the important `User` APIs will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your struct definition for `Rect` must be incorrect. From the string representation, I can tell its members currently are doubles. If you look on MSDN, [RECT structure only has integers in it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//dd162897(v=vs.85)).

Define it like this:

```
struct Rect
{
    public int left;
    public int top;
    public int right;
    public int bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In UWP we can use `ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBounds` to get the VisibleBounds in the main windows.

We can call many dlls as the Win32 application.

We can use `Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBounds` to get the bounding rectangle of the app window. The other way to get current windows is use  `Window.Current.Bounds` to get the bounds.

Comment: I think the OP wants to get the size of the current foreground window of the system, which is a window they don't own. It could be a classic window or a UWP window. Calling VisibleBounds won't do the trick here.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT Yes, exactly. That said, fixing the Rect definition did the trick!

Comment: Also note if you want the rectangle bounds in 'pixels' rather than 'logical pixels', you'll need to use the DPI value to convert the VisibleBounds to pixels.